# How to filter duplicate data and aggregate values in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of networks with each one containing various rows (e.g., network A has 4 rows or 4 instances). I want to be able to sort the data in 'blocks' or segment it in a way where I can easily view aggregates or manipulate the data for each Network.

I want to segment the data via VBA/macro that does this automatically, with the final row for each Network calculating a given metric.

The data, of course, can be filtered this way via the 'filter' option and manually worked on. I'm looking to automate this process via VBA/Macros, can anyone point me towards the right direction or help?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? Sounds like something a pivot table would handle though.

Comment: So I'm going to re-write what you said in a different way to see if I understand what your requirements are:
1. you have a list in each column that is populated with data, which lasts a various amount of rows (column A is across 4 rows, but column B could be across 7, etc)
2. You'd like to sort the data in each column from smallest to largest (or vice versa) so that you can see where multiple instances of the same value occur
3. You'd like a metric regarding this sorting process to be output on the bottom row (can you elaborate?)

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I interpreted what you wanted to do, this is where I'd start:

pt. 1: find the range for data a particular column

```
Dim col_var, first_row, last_row, i As Long, myrang As String

i = 1

'find first & last row of data
col_var = ActiveCell.Column
While Cells(i, col_var) = 0
    i = i + 1
Wend

first_row = i

While Cells(i, col_var) <> 0
    i = i + 1
Wend

last_row = i

'set range
myrang = Cells(first_row, col_var).Address & ":" & Cells(last_row, col_var).Address
```

pt. 2: Then you can just "record macro" to find how to use the filter, and then replace the important bits with "myrang":

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(first_row, col_var).Address), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range(myrang)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

This, at the moment, sorts a column picked by which is the "active column" on the time of starting the macro (i.e. which column you had most recently clicked on before starting the macro). This is found by the line:

```
col_var = ActiveCell.Column
```

however, this could be changed so that it can be:

pt. 3: iterated across for a number of columns, by saying

```
col_var = j
```

and then you can put everything written so far in something that loops j (here I've gone from columns 4 - 8 but you can change this easily to what you want):

```
Sub sorting()

Dim col_var, first_row, last_row, i As Long, myrang As String

for j = 4 to 8
i = 1
'find first & last row of data
col_var = j
While Cells(i, col_var) = 0
    i = i + 1
Wend

first_row = i

While Cells(i, col_var) <> 0
    i = i + 1
Wend

last_row = i

'set range
myrang = Cells(first_row, col_var).Address & ":" & Cells(last_row, col_var).Address


    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(first_row, col_var).Address), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range(myrang)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

next j

End Sub
```